# Windows 7: Audio stream from Default Communications Device with both incoming and outgoing channels?

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio, recording

Is it possible create or otherwise enable a playback interface in Windows 7 that consists of both the incoming and outgoing streams from the Default Communications Device? I've heard this type of thing referred to as a loopback interface, but most googling on this topic refers me to networking loopback interfaces instead.

Basically I'm interested in consuming both halves of communications from this device in other programs that can select their input sources. Seems like this thing should be possible, but I'm not sure it is.